# ASP.Net Session over web / WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, session-state

We have a system with many web servers, where we would like to store the session state in a central location.

At the same time we do not have direct access to the database, due to firewalls.

Has anyone managed to serialize session and send it over a web service for storage in a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement your own [`Session-State Store Provider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx). There is an [MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178588.aspx) you can use as a starting point.

You then can change the [`<sessionState>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx) element in your web.config to use that provider instead of the built-in one.

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement a custom session state store provider, which will perform the required web service calls.

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en/library/ms178587.aspx) is a detailed explanation, and an exemple with a custom ODBC connection. It can easily be updated for your case. I am afraid it's not completely trivial.